# Converting Vector Tiles to Raster Tiles

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles

I have created a Vector tile server using TileserverGL/Tessera. I have exported a few MBTiles layers through Tippecanoe. I must have to use Multiple MBTiles. Then I have designed the map through a JSON file. Now I want to create a similar design Raster Tile Server. How can I get a Raster MBTiles with a similar design?

Comment: What design specifications did you create in the JSON file?

Comment: Mapbox Studio format (Style.json) not in carto CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky but works,

You can merge multiple mbtiles to single mbtiles file then

use: 
`tileserver-gl {filename}.mbtiles`
to serve mbtiles as pbf

(can launch multiple tileserver with different files but will need to configure that in your style)

for pbf to raster:

```
docker run --rm -itd --name rastermap -v $(pwd):/data -p 9090:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl -c config.json --verbose
```

config.json as:

```
{
"styles": {
    "basic": {
        "style": "Style.json",
        "tilejson": {
            "type": "overlay",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 23
        }
    }
}}
```

where Style.json is your style file.It must contain pbf source as new lanched mbtiles tileserver.

Comment: I have merged different mbtiles but the problem is higher zoomscale. Few of my tiles have maxZoom 13, few have 18. if I join all those mbtiles have 13 zoom scale doesn't appear after 13 zoom scale

Comment: BTW, I was following the same approach either.

Comment: @Devils Dream for the  problem with higher zoomscale you can use https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache where the different layers can have different mbtiles sources ,then all layers merged into one composite layer.

Comment: If I use TileStache then what will be the procedure to reproduce the raster from Vector Tiles?

Comment: @Devils Dream In Style.json you can add source of pbf tiles as tilestache host url and then followed by pbf to raster.

Comment: possible to share a sample of "Style.json" ? I'm not able to find one that will fit for : a simple single layer vector tiles source that has just simple polygons and zero attributes.

Comment: https://maputnik.github.io/editor/#6.39/23.678/78.219 can play around in this and export style file.Can look at "landuse" layer for polygons